# Error Jenkins, Could not transfer artifact org.jfrog.jade.plugins.common:

Tags: spring, maven, jenkins

Error when push source code in kubernetes, error jenkins show

Could not transfer artifact org.jfrog.jade.plugins.common:jade-plugin-common:pom:1.3.8 from/to bintray-nitram509-jbrotli (http://dl.bintray.com/nitram509/jbrotli): Access denied to: http://dl.bintray.com/nitram509/jbrotli/org/jfrog/jade/plugins/common/jade-plugin-common/1.3.8/jade-plugin-common-1.3.8.pom

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdAp3.jpg)

But, when i build my project by mvn clean install in return build succes,  but in jenkis it shows error build failed

How to fix this error ? because when i click the link suggest, it shows forbidden

pom.xml

4.0.0
org.idx
lmsadmin
war
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
lmsadmin Maven Webapp
http://maven.apache.org

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
1.5.2.RELEASE

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
        <artifactId>javamelody-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.74.0</version>
    </dependency>





    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
        <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.cssbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdf2dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Where does that dependency come from when you build locally (if you delete it from your local maven repository). What `settings.xml` do you use locally, and what `settings.xml` does your jenkins build use? Is there any `<repositories>` section in your `pom` (or a parent pom)?

Comment: @tgdavies there's no jbrotil dependencies , i dont delete anything , I dont have settings.xml in my source code , and there is no <repositories>

Comment: Is it possible to do exclusions to that dependencies ? @tgdavies

Comment: If you read the error message, you'll see it's a transitive dependency of pdf2dom

Comment: There is some configuration which is trying to use bintray instead of the maven default of https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfrog.jade.plugins.common/jade-plugin-common/1.3.8. Perhaps you can talk to the people who run your Jenkins instance and ask them to investigate

Comment: If you are running on a jenkins instance the jenkins instance should provide a correct `settings.xml` via config file provider plugin and redirect all request to a internal repository manager ...